# Is it possible a gridView has a FocusedRowHandle but on the view we cannot see the row is highlighted?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, highlight

my gridView is with GroupRow - rowHandle is -1, -2, ...
When the gridView is launched, the FocusedRowHandle = -1 -- I hope this gridView can focus and highlight the first group row in the grid.
But very strange, although I see view.FocusedRowHandle = -1, the first group row doesn't get focused nor highlighted. 
Is there any property on the gridView maybe stop the focused group row being highlighted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with other rows also whether selection color is appearing on it after clicking or focusing, if not then you need to set the property "EnableAppearanceFocusedRow" = true......